# Iterate through all the rows and click on the second cell of each row in every iteration in a table

Tags: java, selenium

[image: click here to see the table]

Here is my code.

```js
  // Grab the table
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("Account_body"));

// Now get all the TR elements from the table
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
// And iterate over them, getting the cells
for (WebElement row : allRows) {
 List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a"));
 for (WebElement cell : cells) {
 // And so on   
  cell.click();
            System.out.println("clicked row");
```

Iterate through all the rows and click on the second cell of each row in every iteration in a table HTML:

```html
   
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="list">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="headerRow">
      <th scope="col" class="actionColumn">Action</th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Customer Name - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;srtClmn=ACCOUNT.NAME&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Customer Name</a></th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Customer Site - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;srtClmn=ACCOUNT.SITE&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Customer Site</a></th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Work Phone - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;srtClmn=00NE0000004a58n&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Work Phone</a></th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Customer Owner Alias - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&amp;offset=0&amp;fpg=11nkv2y5sf6ky&amp;str=NELSON%2CEDWIN&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;srtClmn=CORE.USERS.ALIAS&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Customer Owner Alias</a></th>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow even first">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 1 - Nelson,Edwin" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012jqBq/e" data-seclki="001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclkh="fb70693f5a4ab349f7bf6e74c4f8acff" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000012jqBq/e?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3FsearchType%3D2%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26str%3DNELSON%252CEDWIN">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclki="001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclkh="fb70693f5a4ab349f7bf6e74c4f8acff" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000012jqBq?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001">Nelson,Edwin</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(888) 888-8888</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclkh="fb70693f5a4ab349f7bf6e74c4f8acff" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow odd">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 2 - NELSON,EDWIN" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="2" data-seclkp="/001Q0000013hzA7/e" data-seclki="001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclkh="b182c705723f5e1a6f828808c22c20f3" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000013hzA7/e?srPos=1&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3FsearchType%3D2%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26str%3DNELSON%252CEDWIN">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="2" data-seclkp="/001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclki="001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclkh="b182c705723f5e1a6f828808c22c20f3" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000013hzA7?srPos=1&amp;srKp=001">NELSON,EDWIN</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(435) 345-4543</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="2" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclkh="b182c705723f5e1a6f828808c22c20f3" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=1&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow even">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 3 - NELSON,EDWIN" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="3" data-seclkp="/001Q0000014lLNc/e" data-seclki="001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclkh="36ddf075be1199f1439c154f56aa01ee" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000014lLNc/e?srPos=2&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3FsearchType%3D2%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26str%3DNELSON%252CEDWIN">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="3" data-seclkp="/001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclki="001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclkh="36ddf075be1199f1439c154f56aa01ee" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000014lLNc?srPos=2&amp;srKp=001">NELSON,EDWIN</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(444) 444-4444</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="3" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclkh="36ddf075be1199f1439c154f56aa01ee" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=2&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow odd last">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 4 - NELSON,EDWIN" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="4" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012m1Xb/e" data-seclki="001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclkh="71e8dbf22eb142eef3edfd7d3576afae" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000012m1Xb/e?srPos=3&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3FsearchType%3D2%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26str%3DNELSON%252CEDWIN">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="4" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclki="001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclkh="71e8dbf22eb142eef3edfd7d3576afae" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000012m1Xb?srPos=3&amp;srKp=001">NELSON,EDWIN</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(656) 757-5463</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="4" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclkh="71e8dbf22eb142eef3edfd7d3576afae" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=3&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***

Comment: Ok, done. What next? - Seriously, what have _you_ tried so far and where did you fail?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Thomas                                                                                                         
I am unable to click the on second element in the row for every iteration . I have added my code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is written correctly, with closing '}'s in the right location, here are a few thoughts that might help.

First, I don't see the id attribute with the table element, so I would be surprised if this was actually getting the correct element.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("Account_body"));
```

And if that is not the right element, then it is very possible that this:

```
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

is not the rows that you are expecting.

Second when you using WebElement.findElement(By.xpath()), you should, in my opinion, bass it off of the element that you are using to find the other element. So instead of:

```
By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")
```

It should look more like:

```
By.xpath("./td")
```

since the location of the row is already under the table element that you are referencing.

Third, if you are only clicking on the second column of every row, and I expect that you actually are not interested in clicking on the first row since those are just headers, then you should not need to use a second foreach loop.

Forth, is it really the second column that your interested in or is it the customer name column that your interested in?

I would imagine that something like this should work, although you may have to play with the xpaths a little, since I didn't try to actually plug them in to see if they match elements.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']"));

// Now get all the TR elements from the table but excludes the header row
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[not(@class='headerRow')"));
// And iterate over them, getting the cells
for (WebElement row : allRows) {
 //assuming that you are actually trying to click on the link for each user name,
 //and not just the second element
 WebElement cell = row.findElement(By.xpath("./th/a");
 // And so on   
  cell.click();
```

To be honest though I don't know if this will solve your issue. Without any information on why you are not able to click on the second column, this is little more then speculation. If you could include both where the code fails, and the exception error, it would allow others to give a better answer.